# Pandas: Replace values in a column using a mapping between the rows of another column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following DataFrame and dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group_col':['g1','g1','g1','g1','g2','g2','g2','g2'], 'map_col': ['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d'], 'replace_col':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
map_dict = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

Here is `df`:

```
  group_col map_col  replace_col
0        g1       a            1
1        g1       b            2
2        g1       c            3
3        g1       d            4
4        g2       a            5
5        g2       b            6
6        g2       c            7
7        g2       d            8
```

I want to replace values in `replace_col` based on the mapping of `map_col` using `map_dict` for each group in the grouping column `group_col`, obtaining the following dataframe:

```
  group_col map_col  replace_col
0        g1       a            2
1        g1       b            2
2        g1       c            4
3        g1       d            4
4        g2       a            6
5        g2       b            6
6        g2       c            8
7        g2       d            8
```

What would be the best/fastest approach for a large dataframe with many groups and replacements to be made? Assume the entries in `map_col` are not repeated within each group (as in the example above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df['replace_col'] = (df[['group_col']]
    .merge(df, left_on=['group_col', df['map_col'].map(map_dict)],
           right_on=['group_col', 'map_col'], how='left'
          )['replace_col']
    .fillna(df['replace_col']).convert_dtypes()
   )
```

Less efficient alternative with a [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
df['replace_col'] = (df.groupby('group_col')
                       .apply(lambda g: g['map_col'].map(map_dict)
                                      .map(g.set_index('map_col')['replace_col'])
                                     .fillna(g['replace_col']))
                       .droplevel(0).convert_dtypes()
                    )
```

Output:

```
  group_col map_col  replace_col
0        g1       a            2
1        g1       b            2
2        g1       c            4
3        g1       d            4
4        g2       a            6
5        g2       b            6
6        g2       c            8
7        g2       d            8
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, which uses [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['replace_col'] = (
        df.assign(aux = df['map_col'].map(map_dict))
        .groupby('group_col')
        .apply(lambda x: x['aux'].map(dict(zip(x['map_col'], x['replace_col'])))
               .fillna(x['replace_col'])).values.astype(int))
```

Output:

```
  group_col map_col  replace_col
0        g1       a            2
1        g1       b            2
2        g1       c            4
3        g1       d            4
4        g2       a            6
5        g2       b            6
6        g2       c            8
7        g2       d            8
```